# Installation of Ruby On Rails in Ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

i want to ask a method to installation of ruby on rails in xubuntu Operating System. 
i wanna develop website.i have install Xubunru in my laptop.but Ruby development Environment is not installed. please explain me proper method having full tools.in Future when i follow your instruction,Commented below, then development start.. tell me Guys proper solution.

Comment: in Xubuntu #Correction

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Ruby, Rails requires Ruby 1.9.3 or newer.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ruby
   ```
2. Install Rails (this could take a while)

   ```
   sudo gem install rails
   ```

   New versions of Rails can be installed the same way.
3. Install a javascript runtime

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nodejs
   ```
4. Create your application skeleton and start the server:

   ```
   rails new path/to/your/new/application
   cd path/to/your/new/application
   rails server
   ```

You’re running Ruby on Rails! Follow the instructions on http://localhost:3000

[image]

<sub>[source](http://rubyonrails.org/download/)</sub>